# Domain is redirected to another domain in same droplet

Tags: apache, debian, digital-ocean

Well, I am new on Debian, Built server on Digital Ocean with Debian OS.
I successfully added two domains into one droplet:

```
mysite.com
anothersite.com
```

Created new dir:

```
/home/user/www/mysite.com/public_html
```

and copied files to `public_html`

The config file inside `/etc/apache2/sites-available` is:

```
DocumentRoot /home/user/www/mysite.com/public_html

<Directory /home/user/www/mysite.com/public_html>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myproject-error.log
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myproject-access.log combined
```

Of Course, I enabled the site.

I haven't edited `apache2.conf` file and haven't configured 2nd domain (`anothersite.com`). Just added this 2nd domain to droplet, that's all.

when I enter to the site `mysite.com` it works perfect. But I wondered that why 2nd domain (`anothersite.com`) is redirected to 1st (`mysite.com`) domain?

By the way, I use Apache 2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If hostname (e.g. anothersite.com) point to the apache webserver but haven't explicitely configured a  section that matches that hostname, then apache will deliver a "best match" (the first ).

so if only have a single  in apache config and multiple hostnames (mysite.com and anothersite.com) point to the same machine, all of these names will display the same virtual host